# Getting 'HookWebpackError' when upgraded from NEXT 9 to Next 11

Tags: webpack, next.js

I'm trying to upgrade my project from 'NEXT 9' to 'NEXT 11' bug getting error
`HookWebpackError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

As webpack5 is enabled by default in NEXT 11 so I want to use it now.
Anyone knows the reason let me know.

Comment: What specific `next` version are you using? Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: I am upgrading from  "next": "9.4.4" to "next": "^11.1.2". I will try to provide a reproducible example.